# Solidity: memory vs stack

Tags: storage, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

Solidity has 3 difference memory storage: storage, memory and stack. After reading lots of articles online, I still can't understand the difference between memory and stack. My question would be:

Q1. What's the difference between memory and stack?

Q2. Suppose I have defined a local variable in function, how do I know that this variable is stored in memory or stack? (The variable is in memory only if the declaration of the variable goes with the "memory" keyword?)

Thanks, everyone.

---

Thanks for the reply from @Yilmaz .
According to your answer, say we have a function written like this:

```
function test() public {
    string memory str;
    int i;
}
```

Are `str` and `i` both on "memory" and on "stack" simultaneously?

My third question is:

Q3. Why do only array, struct, and mapping types need to specify memory location?
Why Solidity doesn't allow me to write `int memory i;` in above code?

Comment: Likely related: [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) and [In Ethereum Solidity, what is the purpose of the "memory" keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33839154/11082165)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Storage is where the variables are permanently stored on the blockchain. If you want to manipulate the data in storage you copy it to the memory. Then, all memory code is executed on stack. Stack has a maximum
depth of 1024 elements and supports the word size of 256 bits.

When you define the local variable it is stored in memory and then pushed to the stack for execution.

- Stack is a temporary storage that the Ethereum EVM uses to bring
  data from other storage to work on them. `str` and `i` both are not on "memory" and on "stack" simultaneously. You see the image, there is `push` code that moves the variable from memory to stack. If `EVM` was keeping both on the memory and stack instantaneously, it would not be cost efficient.

for your 3rd question please refer this: [In Ethereum Solidity, what is the purpose of the "memory" keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33839154/in-ethereum-solidity-what-is-the-purpose-of-the-memory-keyword)

I explained it with details

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have make an example in my question, please help me verify wether I get this rigtht. Thank you.

Comment: When you define the local variable it is stored in memory and then pushed to the stack for execution. when the function gets executed it is executed on stack. so code is pushed to the stack